# Joining tables with different names to same column

Tags: sql

How do I join 2 tables with different column names with one SQL query?

Lets say I have this table:

```
+----+--------+----------+
| id |  name  |   car    |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 | Name 1 | Audi     |
|  2 | Name 2 | BMW      |
|  3 | Name 3 | Mercedes |
+----+--------+----------+
```

And this table

```
+----+--------+----------+
| id |  name  |   bike   |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 | Name 4 | Kawasaki |
|  2 | Name 5 | Triumph  |
|  3 | Name 6 | Ducati   |
+----+--------+----------+
```

And I want to make this of it

```
+--------+----------+
|  name  |  Brand   |
+--------+----------+
| Name 1 | Audi     |
| Name 2 | BMW      |
| Name 3 | Mercedes |
| Name 4 | Kawasaki |
| Name 5 | Triumph  |
| Name 6 | Ducati   |
+--------+----------+
```

Comment: Where did you get `Name 5 | Triumph ` this from?

Comment: Sorry and thanks for the edit Joel. I changed BMW just in case of confusion but forgot to change it in the second table.

Answer (score 3):

this looks like you want a union

```
SELECT name, car as brand
FROM cars
UNION ALL
SELECT name, bike as brand
FROM bikes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.name, table1.car AS Brand FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT table2.name, table2.bike AS Brand FROM table2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Name, Car from Table1
Union All
Select Name, Bike from Table2
```

I don't know the name of table1 and 2 as you listed but I'm guessing they have something to do with Car and Bike.